# Magento site move causing perpetual waiting

Tags: magento, mamp

I'm attempting to move a magento site from a live site onto my testing server using MAMP. I've done it many times before, and yet this time, strangely, it's causing browsers to hang up when attempting to load any page. Here's what I did:

- -download sql, reinstalled on my localhost, changed the two fields in
  core_config_data.
- -moved all the files to my localhost, removed var/sessions and
  var/cache
- -manually changed the etc/local.xml file to my new localhost
  database, with all the details.

So why would this be causing the site to hang up? I've also attempted to delete etc/local.xml and then run the install. This works fine until the final step, when, blammo, I get a perpetual loading/ waiting for localhost spinning wheel of doom.

Very annoying. Anyone had a similar experience? I'm not quite sure how to even get to the bottom of the problem, as it's not throwing any exceptions or error logs.

Any help, greatly received.

**Edit**

Having run a MySQL profiler (Jet Profiler) whilst attempting to open the site, I've noticed the scans & Innodb cache suddenly max out to 100% and stay that way. No query seems to make it through, or at least none are recorded. Is this simply Magento & my quite large db (46mb) being too much for my macbook, or is it a telltale sign of something else?

Comment: check if you have enough local resources for magento to run, check php error log as well

Comment: Cheers Anton. No php errors but perhaps a resource issue, as it's slowing down my system somewhat. Is there a way I can definitely pinpoint this, see how much memory it's taking up? All other magento installs I have on my machine run fine when loaded.

Comment: verify that your mysql supports innodb and use regular system monitoring apps dependant of the OS you are using

Comment: Scrap that, I just realised I can do that with activity monitor. And yeah, it certainly is rinsing the memory. Dumb question - anyway I can reduce this memory consumption?

Comment: Ensure your db dump is in tact and was imported properly, it sounds like Magento is trying to run some upgrade scripts or such.

Comment: Yeah, it seems to be doing something, at least. It's odd- the db dump seems fine, but weird old Magento definitely seems to be trying it's hardest to do *something* when my RAM goes crazy. Hmmm... bit stuck on this one. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'd suggest running a MySQL profiler and seeing what type of commands are being sent to the database - also, as previously mentioned, make sure you're running InnoDB. Out of curiousity, how large was the SQL file?

Comment: InnoDB is running. The sql file is 46mb. I have a couple of other magento installs on MAMP with similar file sizes, albeit a bit less, running okay. I'll edit above with my findings from a MySQL profiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, that should be all you need to do.  If the site files are good, that's all you ever need to do.  So, if you did all of that correctly, chances are it's a resources issue, or some sort of improper configuration of MAMP or the database.